# Faster method for drawing in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to draw the Mandelbrot fractal, using the following method that I wrote:

```
public void Mendelbrot(int MAX_Iterations)
{
    int iterations = 0;

    for (float x = -2; x <= 2; x += 0.001f)
    {
        for (float y = -2; y <= 2; y += 0.001f)
        {
            Graphics gpr = panel.CreateGraphics();

            //System.Numerics
            Complex C = new Complex(x, y);
            Complex Z = new Complex(0, 0);

            for (iterations = 0; iterations < MAX_Iterations && Complex.Abs(Z) < 2; Iterations++)
                Z = Complex.Pow(Z, 2) + C;

            //ARGB color based on Iterations
            int r = (iterations % 32) * 7;
            int g = (iterations % 16) * 14;
            int b = (iterations % 128) * 2;
            int a = 255;

            Color c = Color.FromArgb(a,r,g,b);
            Pen p = new Pen(c);

            //Tranform the coordinates x(real number) and y(immaginary number) 
            //of the Gauss graph in x and y of the Cartesian graph
            float X = (panel.Width * (x + 2)) / 4;
            float Y = (panel.Height * (y + 2)) / 4;

            //Draw a single pixel using a Rectangle
            gpr.DrawRectangle(p, X, Y, 1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but it's slow, because I need to add the possibility of zooming. Using this method of drawing it isn't possible, so I need something fast. I tried to use a [FastBitmap](http://www.vcskicks.com/fast-image-processing.php), but it isn't enough, the `SetPixel` of the FastBitmap doesn't increase the speed of drawing. So I'm searching for something very fast, I know that C# isn't like `C` and `ASM`, but it would be interesting do this in `C#` and `Winforms`.

Suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT:** [Mendelbrot Set Zoom Animation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jGaio87u3A&feature=related)

Comment: The first thing i'd do is create your graphics object outside the loop.

Comment: The next thing, if you're up to it, is to use something like [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) to do the calculations on the GPU. [Sixty Fractals Per Second](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2006/12/11/sixty-fractals-per-second.aspx)

Comment: Really like the idea. So do you think can I add the XNA libraries and do this in WinForms?

Comment: C# *is* like C or ASM when you use the *unsafe* keyword.  Google "bitmap.lockbits pointers".

Comment: @Fuex:Yes, you can add the XNA libraries to a WinForms Project: [AppHub - WinForms](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1). In your case you'd draw 2 triangles (to make a full screen quad) using a shader you wrote, similar to the one linked in my previous comment

Comment: @George Duckett Ok. Thank you very much for the suggestions!

Comment: Well, in that case your assumptions are your likely problem.  Use a profiler.  Hard to see how it is going to tell you anything else but Complex.Pow() being your real bottleneck.  It ought to burn 99% of all CPU time.

Answer (score 4):

I assume it would be significantly more efficient to first populate your RGB values into a byte array in memory, then write them in bulk into a `Bitmap` using [`LockBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx) and `Marshal.Copy` (follow the link for an example), and finally draw the bitmap using `Graphics.DrawImage`.

You need to understand some essential concepts, such as stride and image formats, before you can get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

As comment said put out `CreateGraphics()` out of the double loop, and this is already a good imrovement.

But also

- Enable double buffering
- For zooming use `MatrixTransformation` functions like:

  [ScaleTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhc2xxtx.aspx)

  [RotateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z3f662.aspx)

  [TranslateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a1d65f4.aspx)

An interesting article on CodeProject can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/matrix_transformation.aspx). It goes a little bit further than just function calls, by explaining actually `Matrix` calculus ( a simple way, don't worry), which is good and not difficult to understand, in order to know what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: The transforms you list probably wouldn't be applicable in this case, as it's the coordinates on the complex number plain that would need transforming (i.e. zooming in, isn't making the image bigger, it's re-drawing with the difference in top-left and bottom-right complex coordinates (+2 and -2 in the code) reduced).

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: don't know what OP means saying "zooming", *I* mean a transformation. That can be easily achieved also on nested loops (if it's necessary) by pushing and poping associated matrix.

Comment: In the context of rendering fractals i assume zooming means rendering a smaller area of the complex plane that previous, which a graphics transform wouldn't help with.